# How to change the default labels of a ForeignKey field whose form's widget is a RadioSelect

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

In my Django app, I have this form:

```py
from django import forms
from main.models import Profile

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['picture']

        widgets = {
            'picture': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

By default, the labels of the `picture` field within the template are generated according to the `__str__()` method of the `Picture` model. That's because the `picture` field on my `Profile` model is actually a ForeignKey field to a `Picture` model.

However, the value returned by that `__str__()` method doesn't make much sense in this particular template, and changing it is not possible because it's being used elsewhere.

Therefore, is there a way I might change the default labels for the `picture` field of my `ProfileForm`? For instance, changing from the `__str__()`'s default `picture.src + ' (' + picture.description + ')'` to something like `picture.description` only?

I have checked [what the docs had to say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.iterator) regarding the `label_from_instance`, but I didn't understand how to apply it. In fact, I couldn't even understand if that would be a solution for this case.

Some similiar questions here on Stack Overflow also mentioned that link of the docs, but the questions's forms were slightly different than mine, and I ended up not understanding them either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I didn't need to use `label_from_instance`. I just needed to create a subclass of django.forms.RadioSelect and override its `create_option()` method, setting the label by giving `option['label']` the value I'd like, just like this:

```py
from django import forms
from main.models import Profile

class PictureRadioSelect(forms.RadioSelect):
    def create_option(self, name, value, label, selected, index, subindex=None, attrs=None):
        option = super().create_option(name, value, label, selected, index, subindex, attrs)
        option['label'] = value.instance.description
        return option

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['picture']

        widgets = {
            'picture': PictureRadioSelect(),
        }
```

[This section of the docs explains this in greater detail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#iterating-relationship-choices). It actually describes how to override django.forms.Select options, but I tested it with django.forms.RadioSelect and it ran as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `label_from_instance`, you should make a specific widget with:

```py
class PictureField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.description


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    picture = PictureField(Picture.objects)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
```

On another hand, you can use your code and in **init** function of your form to change the `choices` attribute of the picture field

Comment: I ended up finding out I didn't need to use label_from_instance (refer to [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69421909/12329214)), but your answer is very useful for those who might need it.

Answer (score 0):

By overriding [**formfield_for_foreignkey()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey), you can display **picture's description** to **Django Admin** without creating **a custom "forms.ModelChoiceField"** and **a custom "forms.ModelForm"** as shown below:

```py
@admin.register(Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        formfield = super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == "picture":
            formfield.label_from_instance = lambda obj: f'{obj.description}'
        return formfield
```